# Explanations on username beside each question?

Tags: support, questions, profile-page

I was looking at the questions list in my profile page and I wonder why it says it has been modified by user Matthias, but opening the question I see no reference to that user:

[Tutorial to implement the use of TabHost in Android 2.2 + ViewPager and Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687717/tutorial-to-implement-the-use-of-tabhost-in-android-2-2-viewpager-and-fragment)

This is a screenshot of my profile page:
[image: My profile page]

Is it because the user posted an answer that has been deleted/not accepted or he modified the question and deleted/cancelled his editing?

Generally, what username and what date is put on the right side of each question?

Sorry if it's a duplicated question, I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736068/matthias) posted a "Thank you" answer, which was then deleted by a moderator.

You cannot see that deleted answer because you don't yet have 10k rep. Here is a screenshot instead:

[image: deleted thank you note]

It is probably a little too complex to show only the last name of *undeleted* answers on question lists; certainly if the (heavily cached) listing had to alter behaviour based on how much reputation the viewer has.

Comment: So it's a decision of SO team to leave there the username that posted a deleted answer?

Comment: @Andreaoid: It is the last username that actively touched your question.

Comment: Everything is clear now, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: And now it is "user2736068" (deleted user).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: the account was never active since and was [automatically deleted](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/).